# How can I grab this website content without losing javascript content

Tags: web, download, offline-browsing, httrack, webgrabber

I want to download this website
Abd i tried idm and httrack but didn't work for javascript content
http://websdr.uk:8074/
Anyone can help me to download this frequency streaming content,

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to capture the javascript actions, you'll need Selenium. It's a browser automation tool, used for Automated testing and data parsing from webpages.

https://www.selenium.dev/

Downloading an entire site is possible only if the website has static pages (HTML, CSS, Img). But Javascript-based content is loaded dynamically, which would be difficult to download.

Comment: This is website
http://websdr.uk:8074/